# Trying to understand basic linker behaviour

Tags: c++, linker

I have a minimal cpp file with contents,

```cpp
int main() {}
```

I then compile and link using

```sh
$ g++ -c main.cpp
$ g++ -o main main.o -Wl,-u,foo
```

*Expected Behaviour:* Since the linker cannot find the symbol foo, because it is not defined anywhere, I expected the linker to throw an error saying that the symbol `foo` is not found/resolved.

*Actual behaviour:* The link step succeeds.

Can someone help me understand this behaviour and how I can force the linker to error out when it cannot find the undefined symbol, possibly using some linker flag?

```sh
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23)
```

Thanks in advance!!!

**EDIT:** It is probably related to my misunderstanding about undefined symbols, so let me clarify my understanding of the linker. The linker searches for undefined symbols in the list sequentially through `-llib...` and `foo` in this case is one such undefined symbol. I was expecting that at the end of traversing the whole list of libraries, there shouldn't be any undefined symbols left i.e. all symbols must be defined. Am I wrong in thinking this?

Comment: Unrelated, but your gcc version is about as old as the dinosaurs.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  You appear to be undefining the symbol `foo` which isn't actually referenced by any part of the code.  Why would the linker complain?

Comment: @G.M. Edited the question to clarify more.

Comment: In your edit you state `"The linker searches for undefined symbols in the list..."`.  If that's changed to `"The linker searches for` **referenced** `but undefined symbols in the list..."` does that clarify things?

Comment: @G.M. I didn't know there was a distinction. I should probably learn more about how a linker works.

Answer (score 1):

That's simply not what `-Wl,u` does. From the `ld` documentation: "Force symbol to be entered in the output file as an undefined symbol.". So the `-u` creates a symbol table in your `main` executable, and adds `foo` to that.

I.e. the option doesn't affect whether an output file is generated.

You may want to try `g++ -c main.cpp -u foo` - pass it to the compiler instead of the linker, so the compiler can put `foo` in the symbol table of `main.o`. Now the linker will see `foo` in its inputs, and it will need to act on that.

Comment: I couldn't make it work. I did `g++ -c main.cpp -u foo` followed by `g++ -o main main.o` and it links perfectly fine.

Comment: Also, what did you mean when you said `I.e. the option doesn't affect whether an output file is generated.`? Assuming you meant no additional object files are included in the executable from specifying `-Wl,u`, then what is its use case? I thought that's what it is used for - including additional object files.

Comment: @MutableSideEffect: The option is most sensible when you use it to pull the extern symbol from a library. You'll then get the entire Translation Unit in which `foo` was defined.

Comment: @MutableSideEffect Having re-read the question I think you need to also specify `-Wl,--require-defined,foo` in order to get the behaviour you expected: i.e. deliberately undefine the symbol `foo` and have the link stage fail unless `foo` is subsequently defined in a library.

Comment: @G.M. I don't think `--require-defined` is a valid `ld` option

Comment: @MutableSideEffect Works for me: `GNU ld (GNU Binutils; openSUSE Tumbleweed) 2.33.1.20191023-3`.  Availability/syntax obviously linker dependent though.

Comment: @G.M. I was looking at an older version of the linker. I checked with a newer version and it seems to work as expected. If you add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.